# usage of words-round and around

Tags: word-usage

**The masters, many of them young men who agreed that Chips was hopelessly old-fashioned, rallied *round* him**

Why is it *round him* and not *around him*?
What's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Here, **round** acts as a *adverb* which modifies **rallied**.

Merriam Webster on [second](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/round) meaning of **round**:

> Definition: ***around***
>
> > Usage: people working there all year **round**

Comment: Please elaborate it further. 
**Sir John had said, on that morning in 1908, taking Chips by the arm as they walked round the deserted cricket pitches..**

Comment: **round** is also used as *adverb* just like **around** (also an adverb) having exactly same meaning. Round and Around are synonym when round is used as adverb :)

Comment: @FatimaFaraz Sir John, was moving **around** in deserted cricket pitches.

Comment: I took this line from the novel **Good Bye Mr. Chips** by *James Hilton*.
Shall I regard it as a grammatical mistake there?

Comment: @FatimaFaraz no it is not. Round = around, when round is used as adverb. In your sentence "round" is used as adverb, so it has a same meaning as "around". It is not grammatical mistake or a typo.

Answer (score -1):

**Both are the same**, and **both are acceptable**, though "round" was more common in the past. "Around" is the preferred word now. "Round" is somewhat more common in British English than American English, but "around" is the preferred word in both places.

Comment: Are you sure? Where is your evidence that "around" is now preferred in BrE?  Maybe I read too much PG Wodehouse, but Bertie Wooster is continually calling on Jeeves to "rally round".

Comment: An Ngrams search result. It's not the most rigorous source, but it illustrates the fact that you can (and do) see both forms. Before the 1990's, "round" was more popular in British English, but was passed by a small margin by "around" in the 90's, which has narrowed considerably since. In American English, "around" has been preferred by a much larger margin since around 1860. For your specific example, Mr. Wodehouse lived around 50 years ago, which places him firmly in the past. (I did not state that "past" was a distant past, simply before now.)

Comment: Ngrams Search: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gather+round%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cgather+around%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cgather+round%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cgather+around%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgather%20round%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgather%20around%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgather%20round%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgather%20around%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0